# Which can be gathered most likely to be encountered? - Test 3, Q25, by Mark Shepherd

Tags: difference, ambiguity

From [*Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&hl=fr&pg=PA144#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Mark Shepherd, page 144, last para:

> ...Second is the idea that the experience of long- term unemployment may be less stigmatising,
>   and hence less stressful and health damaging, in areas where unemployment
>   rates have been traditionally high. **Where the chances of unemployment are perceived
>   as higher and jobs, once lost, more difficult to regain, being unemployed may be seen
>   as more of the norm, rather than a defi ciency of the individual.** Conversely, in more
>   prosperous areas, with lower unemployment, being unemployed for a long time may
>   be perceived as an aberrant and personally stigmatising situation...

[Question 25, p.145](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&hl=fr&pg=PA145#v=onepage&q&f=false):

Which of these situations can be gathered to be most likely to be
encountered?
(a) Under- reporting of unemployment in areas of low long- term unemployment
(b) Under- reporting of unemployment in areas of high long- term unemployment
(c) Over- reporting of unemployment in areas of low long- term unemployment
(d) Over- reporting of unemployment in areas of high long- term unemployment
(e) None of the above

[From the answer key, p.236:](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xdgcAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA132&hl=fr&pg=PA236#v=onepage)

(a) CORRECT. It is stated that ‘in more prosperous areas, with lower unemployment,
being unemployed for a long time may be perceived as an aberrant
and personally stigmatising situation’. This implies that people are likely to
under- report unemployment in such areas.
(b), (e) INCORRECT. See (a).
(c), (d) INCORRECT. The article does not address the issue of over- reporting of
unemployment.

Why's (d) wrong? Doesn't the bolded prove it?  Can't the answer key's argument be reused to argue (d)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the logical interplay of a very specific set of elements within a single passage. The issue, as described, cannot be resolved by any increase to English fluency such as this community is equipped to provide. A high level of fluency is required merely to understand the question as well as the querant already does, and it is unlikely to have any bearing on the efforts of present or future users to further their English language learning.

Comment: Please discuss the proposed closure of this and several similar questions [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/english-reasoning-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can not. An that is because the situations are not symmetrical.

If I feel bad about reporting that I am unemployed, I may decide not to do it (under-reporting.

On the other hand, even if being unemployed is not bad, why would I report myself as unemployed when I have a job (over-reporting)?

The fact that it is seen as the norm, and not as my personal failure, does not make it something I want to do!

Now, if the author would say that being unemployed is seen as a good thing, something that gives me status, yes, maybe d) is conceivable.

The bold part shows that there is nothing to stop people from reporting as unemployed *when they are unemployed*. But that is not over-reporting.